# Button Positioning Issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // Select all the read more buttons and hidden contents
  const readMoreButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more");
  const hiddenContents = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
  // Now loop over the read more buttons 
  readMoreButtons.forEach((readMoreButton, index) => {
    // Add onclick event listeners to all of them
    readMoreButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // Change content of read more button to read less based on the textContent
      if (readMoreButton.textContent === "Read More") {
        readMoreButton.textContent = "Read Less";
      } else {
        readMoreButton.textContent = "Read More";
      }
      // Toggle class based on index
      hiddenContents[index].classList.toggle("hidden");
      readMoreButton.closest(".snip1311").classList.toggle("reading");
    })
  })
})
```

```css
/* Projects */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
.project-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}
figure.snip1311.reading {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

figure.snip1311 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 360px;
  max-height: 256px;
  width: 500rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #07090c;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-perspective: 50em;
  perspective: 50em;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}
figure.snip1311 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
figure.snip1311 img {
  max-width: 110%;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 258px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
figure.snip1311 img {
  border: none;
  }
}
figure.snip1311 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
figure.snip1311 h3,
figure.snip1311 p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
figure.snip1311 h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
figure.snip1311 p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more1 {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}
figure.snip1311 .read-more1:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
figure.snip1311:hover img,
figure.snip1311.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}
figure.snip1311:hover figcaption,
figure.snip1311.hover figcaption {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.hidden{
display:none;
}
.read-more{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/tClzdZVdo_baMV7YA_9HjggPk9k=/4169x2778/filters:fill(auto,1)/the-difference-between-trees-and-shrubs-3269804-hero-a4000090f0714f59a8ec6201ad250d90.jpg" alt="sample98"/>
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sed orci interdum, eleifend nisl suscipit, ornare urna. Curabitur vel maximus lacus. In ut mauris convallis, pellentesque tortor sed, aliquet magna.</p>
    <div class="read-more">Read More</div>
    <br>
    <p class="hidden"><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sed orci interdum, eleifend nisl suscipit, ornare urna. Curabitur vel maximus lacus. In ut mauris convallis, pellentesque tortor sed, aliquet magna. Nam maximus odio eget semper laoreet. In ut vehicula tortor. Suspendisse iaculis, erat eget ultricies iaculis, metus ex cursus libero, sed porttitor justo turpis sit amet lectus. Maecenas mattis tempus orci, vel bibendum erat convallis a.Nam ultrices sapien vel nisl maximus, pretium porta nisl bibendum. Nullam ut arcu id est tristique mollis quis id diam. Proin accumsan pellentesque felis. Integer sollicitudin orci congue enim mollis, elementum auctor eros imperdiet. Etiam et fermentum tellus, a pharetra purus. Integer fringilla urna vel lorem finibus commodo. Mauris interdum justo sed nibh efficitur tincidunt.Donec lectus arcu, vulputate ac egestas sed, feugiat vitae ex. Vestibulum eget tristique nulla. Aliquam et tellus rutrum nulla elementum ultrices. Etiam dapibus fringilla magna ac eleifend. Cras turpis nibh, accumsan ut quam non, laoreet porttitor sapien. Etiam consequat turpis lobortis finibus tempus. Suspendisse rhoncus tincidunt bibendum. Donec sagittis, felis non elementum dapibus, justo mauris luctus libero, a ultricies tortor mi et risus. Fusce aliquet, lacus id tincidunt vestibulum, turpis augue porta tellus, eget porta ante erat ut sem. Integer eu mi turpis. Proin bibendum pellentesque massa, sit amet sodales dui mollis et. Curabitur malesuada elit nisi, nec congue tellus congue id. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse imperdiet, sem ut rutrum condimentum, justo lacus lobortis nisl, id mollis nisl ipsum sit amet nunc. Sed et ex leo.</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

When you run the above code, you can see that when you click the `read more` button, the button suddenly disappears. It is because the text is really long so the button disappears at the top. How would I make it so that the `read-more` button is always at the top regardless of how long the text is.

### Expected Output

[image]

I want the same margin the `read more` button has with the top of the card. Otherwise, nothing else should change, like the alignment of the button should not change at all. Its just that the button should appear with the same `margin-top` as shown in the expected output, regardless of how long the text is. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Side-note: don't use `<div>` for buttons, it's problematic for accessibility and a bunch of other things. Use a `<button>`.

Comment: To add to msanford comment - use `<button type="button" aria-controls="product-123">` (which controls some `#product-123` ID) Read also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role

Comment: Would that solve the problem?

Comment: The flipping element is centering in the available space, then it is overflowing, from center both ways an amount equal to half the content size less half the height of your parent element. You COULD add a class to the hidden element when shown, use tranlateY to push the element down to the top, however you would need to find an  algorythm that would take the height of the content and the height of the parent element and calculate that to then send that amount over to CSS via the root element and assign it to the shsown element class. Or figure out how to flip the element on the top axis.

Answer (score 1):

Your element is being flipped from the center, and it is overflowing to the top of the scrollable element, placing the text somewhere in the mid-top from center depending on the content in the element when it is no longer hidden.

EDIT: You have two instances in your CSS where you are placing `translate(0%, -50%)` the second is for Y axis, this is puching your elements content 50% up the element and creating the issue with the top not being seen.

Get the clientHeight of the flipped element by first adding a class, `shown`, to the element once `hidden` is removed. Then set a timeout to `10` to make sure the DOM is set before then getting the added class `shown`/s clientHeight. Then divide the client half by 2 and subtract half of the parent elements height to locate the top of your content, not excluding padding.

Now take this unit and pass that to your CSS via a variable using the root element => `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--distTrans', 'distance')`. This will set a vriable in CSS to the distance we want to set the top of our flipped content. Then in CSS, set the `shown` selectors **transform** property to `translateY(var(--distTrans))`, this will slide the text down to the top of the content, padding not included.

```js
function showLess(e) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.showBtn').forEach(btn => {
    if (e.target === btn) {
      btn.closest(".snip1311").classList.toggle("reading");
      btn.parentNode.classList.toggle('shown')
      btn.parentNode.classList.toggle('hidden')
    }
  })
}

function parseContent(event) {
  // Select all the read more buttons and hidden contents
  const readMoreButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more");
  const hiddenContents = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
  // Now loop over the read more buttons 
  readMoreButtons.forEach((readMoreButton, index) => {
    // Add onclick event listeners to all of them
    readMoreButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // this calculates the height of your shown elements contentby 2
        // and then subtracts the half of the height of the parent element
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--transDist', document.querySelector('.shown').clientHeight / 2 - document.querySelector('.snip1311').clientHeight / 2 + 'px');
      }, 10);
      // Toggle class based on index
      hiddenContents[index].classList.toggle("hidden");
      hiddenContents[index].classList.toggle("shown");
      
      let shown = document.querySelectorAll('.shown')
      if (shown) {
        shown.forEach(item => {
          item.addEventListener('click', showLess)
        })
      }
      readMoreButton.closest(".snip1311").classList.toggle("reading");
    })
  })
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", parseContent)
```

```css
/* Projects */

:root {
  --transDist: 100px;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
.project-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

figure.snip1311.reading {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

figure.snip1311 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 360px;
  max-height: 256px;
  width: 500rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #07090c;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-perspective: 50em;
  perspective: 50em;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

figure.snip1311 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

figure.snip1311 img {
  max-width: 110%;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 258px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  figure.snip1311 img {
    border: none;
  }
}

figure.snip1311 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

figure.snip1311 h3,
figure.snip1311 p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

figure.snip1311 h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

figure.snip1311 p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

figure.snip1311 .read-more:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  outline: none;
}

figure.snip1311:hover img,
figure.snip1311.hover img {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

figure.snip1311:hover figcaption,
figure.snip1311.hover figcaption {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translate(0, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}

figure.snip1311 .hidden {
  display: none;
}

figure.snip1311 .shown {
  transform: translateY(var(--transDist));
  padding-bottom: .3rem;
}

.showBtn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  margin-top: -4rem;
}

.showBtn:nth-of-type(2){
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

.showBtn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
}

.shown-title {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<figure class="snip1311"><img src="https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/tClzdZVdo_baMV7YA_9HjggPk9k=/4169x2778/filters:fill(auto,1)/the-difference-between-trees-and-shrubs-3269804-hero-a4000090f0714f59a8ec6201ad250d90.jpg" alt="sample98" />
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sed orci interdum, eleifend nisl suscipit, ornare urna. Curabitur vel maximus lacus. In ut mauris convallis, pellentesque tortor sed, aliquet magna.</p>
    <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
    <br>
    <p class="hidden">
      <button class="showBtn">Read Less</button>
      <b class="shown-title">Lorem ipsum</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sed orci interdum, eleifend nisl suscipit, ornare urna. Curabitur vel maximus lacus. In ut mauris convallis, pellentesque tortor sed, aliquet magna.
      Nam maximus odio eget semper laoreet. In ut vehicula tortor. Suspendisse iaculis, erat eget ultricies iaculis, metus ex cursus libero, sed porttitor justo turpis sit amet lectus. Maecenas mattis tempus orci, vel bibendum erat convallis a.Nam ultrices
      sapien vel nisl maximus, pretium porta nisl bibendum. Nullam ut arcu id est tristique mollis quis id diam. Proin accumsan pellentesque felis. Integer sollicitudin orci congue enim mollis, elementum auctor eros imperdiet. Etiam et fermentum tellus,
      a pharetra purus. Integer fringilla urna vel lorem finibus commodo. Mauris interdum justo sed nibh efficitur tincidunt.Donec lectus arcu, vulputate ac egestas sed, feugiat vitae ex. Vestibulum eget tristique nulla. Aliquam et tellus rutrum nulla
      elementum ultrices. Etiam dapibus fringilla magna ac eleifend. Cras turpis nibh, accumsan ut quam non, laoreet porttitor sapien. Etiam consequat turpis lobortis finibus tempus. Suspendisse rhoncus tincidunt bibendum. Donec sagittis, felis non elementum
      dapibus, justo mauris luctus libero, a ultricies tortor mi et risus. Fusce aliquet, lacus id tincidunt vestibulum, turpis augue porta tellus, eget porta ante erat ut sem. Integer eu mi turpis. Proin bibendum pellentesque massa, sit amet sodales
      dui mollis et. Curabitur malesuada elit nisi, nec congue tellus congue id. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse imperdiet, sem ut rutrum condimentum, justo lacus lobortis nisl, id mollis
      nisl ipsum sit amet nunc. Sed et ex leo.
      
      <button class="showBtn">Read Less</button>
    </p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Hey, could you also add the button element to the show element if possible? I can refer to it and make changes for the similar issue I am facing. Thanks

Comment: @AbiaOmer check out snippit I added a function to add it.  Make sure to note the JS changes as well I removed the conditinal that changes the text to the button and simply added a button directly into the shown content and call a function with a different event listener.

Comment: The content slide using the CSS variable should be dynamic depending on the height of your content too.

Comment: it wont scroll once I click th read less button twice

Comment: Ahh the figure tags class needs the ***reading*** class on the other event to add oveflowY scroll, lemmie fix.... @AbiaOmer, fixed.